# There is error when I upload code to the Arduino UNO

Tags: arduino, arduino-uno

I cannot upload code to Arduino UNO
Error message:

```
avrdude: ser_open(): can't open device "/dev/ttyUSB0": Permission denied
```

Failed uploading: uploading error: exit status 1

Board info:

```
BN: Unknown board
VID: 0x1a86
PID: 0x7523
SN: (null)
```

Comment: How did you install Arduino in your Linux? You have to add your user to the dialmod group.  run `sudo usermod -a -G dialout <username>`  where <username> is your user name.

Comment: https://docs.arduino.cc/software/ide-v1/tutorials/Linux#please-read

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your user to the dialmod group. run

```
 sudo usermod -a -G dialout <username>
```

where  is your user name